spresenseでsshサーバに直接ファイル送信ができるのか
タイトルに書いてある通りのことなのですが、spresenseのマイクロSDカード内に入っているファイル(テキストファイルなり、jpegファイルなり)を直接sshサーバに送ることは可能なのでしょうか？

いばらの道かもしれない方法
MicroPython or CircuitPython で libssh2を利用し scp を行う

MicroPython ESP32 に SSH module がある模様
MicroPython メインストリームには SSH module未だ無さそう https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=7620
Spresenseは, CircuitPython使えそうだが MicroPython見かけない Spresenseの拡張ボードが反応しなくなりました。

元のソース持ってきて「なんとか」すれば使えるかもしれません
乱暴に言ってしまえば, アーキテクチャー似たようなものだし(ARM系), MicroPython と CircuitPythonも似たようなものなので
現実的かもしれない方法
暗号化処理(CPU処理能力的問題), 直接の送信は諦める
(先の方法は, フォーラム内容からすれば 簡単という声もあるが, 対処できないなら諦めることになるでしょう)
シリアル接続 ＆ ssh client機能を備えたマシン(例えばラズパイのような) で中継する。
Zmodem などでファイル転送を行い, 中継機はファイル転送されたら scp を行う

SpresenseのSDKにはmbedtlsが入っているようなので、
セキュアソケットはこれを使えば作れそうです。
軽くググってみたところ（ssh mbedtls implementation source code というキーワードで）、
libssh2というライブラリのコードがヒットしました。
https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/tree/master
この中に、mbedtlsを使うようなコードが入っているようなので、
libssh2をSpresenseにポーティングすれば、
質問者さんのやりたいことが出来そうです。
https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/master/src/mbedtls.c
補足ですが、sshのプロトコルは、
https://www.openssh.com/specs.html
https://tex2e.github.io/rfc-translater/html/rfc4254.html
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4253
https://tex2e.github.io/rfc-translater/html/rfc4253.html
このあたりにまとまっているようです。

その、spresenseなるものにsshクライアントを実装すれば可能ですね
